# search Big data table

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, search, clustered-index

I have a table with 10 million records. Each record indicates one person. Each record has person_id, latitude, longitude, postal-code. I want to pick one query and tell how many other people in 10 miles radius (Distance can be calculated from Latitudes and Longitudes). Searching 10 million records and calculating distance to check if inside 10 million is not a good way. So, I will search only in neighboring postal codes(I will get it somehow). How can I search entry having specific postal code(not all 10 million records)?

Answer (score 1):

Why not take lat/long and create a box extending 10 miles in all four directions first?

Then issue a query looking for people with lat/long in that box. Use a WHERE that does

```
x > xLess10 and x < xPlus10 and y > yLess10 and y < yPlus10
```

Now you have a smaller list and you can calculate the actual distance with something similar to `sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)` for that smaller list. But it has to work on a sphere, not a grid marked off in miles.

You can try adding a `and zip in (555555, 555556, etc)` to see if that runs faster or not. A precomputed list of all other zip codes with locations within 10 miles of anywhere within a zip code would be pretty easy to set up in another table.

@Randy made a comment that made me realize that this doesn't work very well for locations within 10 miles of the north and south poles. Maybe that doesn't matter because the population is pretty small up there. Or use another method of just getting everyone within a cirle around the pole and 10 miles south (or north) or the x,y location.

Also, you have to find a way to convert from lat/long to miles. The longitudinal lines get closer together the farther you are from the equator.

Comment: or it might be good enugh to just keep the box as the approximation for 'closeness' - watch out that your circle equation is not exactly correct for GREAT CIRCLE DISTANCE either.